# Restkit Object Mapping Two Classes Bad Access

Tags: objective-c, core-data, restkit

I am mapping two classes of objects with RestKit. When I do either of them by themselves, it works out perfectly fine. But when I call them together, it will crash on line `449` in `RKObjectMappingOperation.m`,

```
[destinationSet setSet:destinationObject];
```

With an `"EXC_BAD_ACCESS"` error.

Here are my two mapping methods:

```
- (RKObjectLoader *)saves
{
    // Create an object manager and connect core data's persistent store to it
    RKObjectManager *objectManager = [RKObjectManager sharedManager];
    RKManagedObjectStore* objectStore = [RKManagedObjectStore objectStoreWithStoreFilename:@"Db.sqlite"];
    objectManager.objectStore = objectStore;

    // Define our author mapping for saved places
    RKManagedObjectMapping *authorMapping = [RKManagedObjectMapping mappingForEntityWithName:@"Person"];
    [authorMapping mapAttributes:@"uid", nil];

    // Define our place mapping
    RKManagedObjectMapping *placeMapping = [RKManagedObjectMapping mappingForEntityWithName:@"Place"];
    [placeMapping mapAttributes:@"uid",@"name",@"address", nil];

    // Now, connect the two via a save
    RKManagedObjectMapping *saveMapping = [RKManagedObjectMapping mappingForEntityWithName:@"Save"];
    [saveMapping mapAttributes:@"uid", @"timestamp", nil];

    [saveMapping mapKeyPath:@"place" toRelationship:@"place" withMapping:placeMapping];
    [saveMapping mapKeyPath:@"author" toRelationship:@"author" withMapping:authorMapping];

    // We expect to find the place entity inside of a dictionary keyed "saves"
    [objectManager.mappingProvider setMapping:saveMapping forKeyPath:@"saves"];

    // Prepare our object loader to load and map objects from remote server, and send
    RKObjectLoader *objectLoader = [objectManager objectLoaderWithResourcePath:@"places/saves" delegate:self];
    objectLoader.method = RKRequestMethodGET;
    [objectLoader send];

    return objectLoader;
}

- (RKObjectLoader *)recommends
{
    // Create an object manager and connect core data's persistent store to it
    RKObjectManager *objectManager = [RKObjectManager sharedManager];
    RKManagedObjectStore* objectStore = [RKManagedObjectStore objectStoreWithStoreFilename:@"Db.sqlite"];
    objectManager.objectStore = objectStore;

    // Define our author mapping for recommended places
    RKManagedObjectMapping *authorMapping = [RKManagedObjectMapping mappingForEntityWithName:@"Person"];
    [authorMapping mapAttributes:@"uid", nil];

    // Define our place mapping
    RKManagedObjectMapping *placeMapping = [RKManagedObjectMapping mappingForEntityWithName:@"Place"];
    [placeMapping mapAttributes:@"uid",@"name",@"address", nil];

    // Now, connect the two via a recommend
    RKManagedObjectMapping *recommendMapping = [RKManagedObjectMapping mappingForEntityWithName:@"Recommend"];
    [recommendMapping mapAttributes:@"uid", @"timestamp", nil];

    [recommendMapping mapKeyPath:@"place" toRelationship:@"place" withMapping:placeMapping];
    [recommendMapping mapKeyPath:@"author" toRelationship:@"author" withMapping:authorMapping];

    // We expect to find the place entity inside of a dictionary keyed "recommends"
    [objectManager.mappingProvider setMapping:recommendMapping forKeyPath:@"recommends"];

    // Prepare our object loader to load and map objects from remote server, and send
    RKObjectLoader *objectLoader = [objectManager objectLoaderWithResourcePath:@"places/recommends" delegate:self];
    objectLoader.method = RKRequestMethodGET;
    [objectLoader send];

    return objectLoader;
}
```

When I call one, or the other, it works. When I call both,

```
[self saves];
[self recommends];
```

It crashes. Any idea why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The call to set `objectManager.objectStore` is causing the previously set `objectStore` to be released from `objectManager`. The first call, `[self saves]` creates and sets an `objectStore` object, then second call `[self recommends]` repeats this, thereby removing the first one set in `[self saves]`. Some time during the processing started off by `[self saves]`, the original (released) `objectStore` object is being accessed, hence the crash.

A potential fix would be to refactor out the `objectStore` setter into a separate method which is called by both methods, or wrap it in an `if (!objectManager.objectStore) { ... }` statement.